# How to make sure load complete in crm page

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I work with dynamics-crm 2016, my mission is - after the user click on new button (on form -to create a new record) the ***new*** form will load, I need to check a certain field and according to that field to lock my form.

When I check it from onLoad function the field is null, how can I check that my page has been loaded or all my fields are full in Xrm /Crm?
My code:

```
function OnLoad() {
        try {

             if (formType == formTypes.Create) {
      checkNeedsUnique();      
      }

    } catch (e) {
        frameworkGlobal.reportExceptionToServer(e);
    }            
};
```

//the function

```
function checkNeedsUnique(){
//portfolio return Null     
   var portfolio = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("protfolioid").getValue();
           var filter = "needsSet?$select=needsId&$filter=protfolioid/Id eq guid'"+ portfolio[0].id+"' and statecode/Value eq 0";
           var ret = frameworkGlobal.RetrieveMultiple(filter, false);
           if(!!ret && ret.length>0){          
           disableAllFields();
           }

        }
```

Comment: Put your tried code here, which you already done

Comment: @fool-dev I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling your function `OnLoad` from onLoad event of your form, then all the fields have already been loaded. You cannot call it from some `$(document).ready` because it will not work correctly.

The field that you are checking (the `portfolio`) must exist on the form (or if you have Dynamics 365 9.0 you can add this field as your script [dependencies](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2017/12/dependent-attributes-in-javascript-in-dynamics-365-v9-0/)). It can be hidden or it can be placed on some hidden section but it must be there, I believe that you did not put it on the form, or you put it on the header (where you should refer to it as `"header_portfolioid"`), that's why you are getting null.

If by any means you cannot put it on the form, you will have to retrieve it's value using API call.

Comment: the field is on the form.

Comment: @Damkulul If the field is on the form and your onLoad is called from CRM's OnFormLoad your fields will already be loaded and accessible.  Looks like to me you spelled "portfolio" wrong

Answer (score 1):

Is this a typo in the attribute name?

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("protfolioid").getValue();
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("portfolioid").getValue();
```